# Laravel Mail Service with Mailgun

Tags: laravel, mailgun

I'm setting mailgun with this environment :

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=sandbox48ec558**********************.mailgun.org
MAILGUN_SECRET=key-2***************************0
```

but when i try to sending email, this message shows up:

```
Client error: `POST 
https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox48ec558923d24853ac621e5582822b69.mailgun.org/messages.mime` resulted in a `400 BAD REQUEST` response:
{
"message": "Business Verification"
}
```

what wrong with my setting?

it's say **Client error**

what is Bussiness Verification?

How to fix it?

Comment: `400` is Bad Request, the `message` tells you the problem.

Comment: @ash yes i know that, but i don't know what is Business Verification, i search the documentation but i didn't find it.

Comment: You likely don't have your DNS records configured properly: https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/202850080-What-does-business-verification-is-required-mean-

Answer (score 1):

According to [Mailgun](https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/202850080-What-does-business-verification-is-required-mean-) you need to go and verify your DNS records.

> Also ensure you have added your custom domain and update your domain's DNS with your DNS provider. The records you need to add can be found on the Domains tab in your Mailgun Control Panel.